# I'm on your desk, On water, At water's edge, Mostly water, Best kept dry - What am I?

Tags: riddle, homonym

I'm on your desk, On water, At water's edge, Mostly water, Best kept dry

Plug me, Turn me, Make me, Pour me, Pass me

I'm usually female, Relative to whole, Relative to air, An acquired taste, Best not lost

Connect me, Face me, Call me, Drink me, Show me

**What am I?**

Hint:

> Try looking at the first clue on each line, then the second on each line and so on.  Probably a good way to set out the answer too.

Comment: I as thinking about resistance or charge but no; neither is feminine :/

Comment: It's a nice thought but it probably only applies to about one fifth. :)

Comment: I thought we already settled this one. You're Brent Hackers, remember?

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan Hmph... >:\  I hope this doesn't appear on all my puzzles from now on.

Comment: @BrentHackers And all clues refer to a single object?

Comment: @Areeb: There's a homonym tag, so probably not.

Comment: @MOehm I figured that referred to the clues as being homonyms

Comment: @Areeb Nope, the answer is indeed a homonym +1 M Oehm

Comment: Alright, that makes things clearer. I might have something since that's true

Comment: following your hint, I am thinking of power bank!(it is the only thing I have on my desk right now) Is it close?or even relative?

Comment: Sorry @Smriti  That's not it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm going for

I'm on your desk, Plug me, I'm usually female, Connect me

> Computer hardware port ( interface between a computer and other electronic devices) which you connect a plug into - in device terms the plug called the male part socket the female part.

On water, Turn me, Relative to whole, Face me

> On a ship the port is the left side and the ship may turn port side.  There may be a porthole which you may look through.

At water's edge,  Make me, Relative to air, Call me

> A port may be a place like Portrush near the sea, a boat may make for port, similar version on sea to airport for aircraft.  Port of call is a good pub's name.

Mostly water, Pour me, An acquired taste, Drink me

> Port - the drink - which may be less than 20% alcohol - the rest water!  A red fortified wine, originally from Portugal.

Best kept dry, Pass me, Best not lost, Show me

> Dry ports may include facilities for storage of goods. May say pass the port and also adding Pass to port gives passports (don't want to lose this) and you will have to show your passport at borders.

**OP Explanations**

I'm on your desk, Plug me, I'm usually female, Connect me

> A Computer Port

On water, Turn me, Relative to whole, Face me

> Port - a leftward direction or orientation relative to a ship or similar

At water's edge,  Make me, Relative to air, Call me

> Port - a place in which you would enter a state/country or similar

Mostly water, Pour me, An acquired taste, Drink me

> Port - booze

Best kept dry, Pass me, Best not lost, Show me

> A Passport

Comment: How does this comply with the homonym tag?

Comment: From the homonym tag: Puzzles may involve a homonym, a word with two or more meanings and a single spelling and/or pronunciation. This puzzle has the same spelling for port but different meanings, also has the same pronunciation involving whole.

Comment: Oh alright, I didn't notice port with all the explanation,  "Portugal" seems like a bit of a stretch though

Comment: Ahh ok you fixed it, nice job

Comment: Correct and well explained.  +1

Comment: @Areeb - thanks yes I just added in Port (maybe in my over familiarity I left it out!

Comment: @BrentHackers - Trying to redeem myself after my last answer which was more suited to what the fish said when it swam into a wall

Comment: @Tom Entirely unnecessary really, but I've updated with my explanation.

Answer (score 1):

I don't currently see how to make this an actual answer but

> all the "--- me" clues are consistent with the answer UP (plug up a hole, turn up = appear, make up after an argument or with cosmetics, pour up = pour, pass up = decline, connect up = connect, face up (to) = admit and deal with, call up = conscript, drink up = drink, show up = appear).

But although this seems to work OK with lines 2 and 4, I don't see how to fit it with lines 1 and 3. So either (most likely) it's just wrong and something else entirely is needed, or else (less likely) we need one answer for lines 1 and 3 and one for 2 and 4 and must combine them (or something of the kind).

Comment: Most likely has it.  It's something else entirely.

Comment: I'm glad to see my intuition is good :-).